# Parser generator for C# target that enables IntelliSense-like code auto-completion?

Tags: parser, autocomplete

I'm looking for a parser generator that generates a C# parser for a relatively simple grammar. The generated parser should make it easy to implement IntelliSense-like code auto-completion based on the grammar.

In a nutshell I'm looking for pretty much something like [Eclipse Xtext](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/) with two differences:

1. It generates the parser as C# code.
2. It allows me to add an IntelliSense-like code auto-completion feature easily to my end product (not to my IDE as Xtext* does), preferrably using a [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)-based approach.

What alternatives do I have based on these requirements?

---

What I found so far is only this (hopefully highly incomplete) list:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28294/a-Tiny-Parser-Generator-v
- ANTLR with something along the lines of this: https://blog.logentries.com/2015/06/how-to-implement-antlr4-autocomplete/

---

* I have used Xtext only to extend the Eclipse IDE so far - therefore I don't know if it also supports to easily put the auto-completion features into a non-Eclipse stand-alone application.

By the way: This is a re-post of [a question that did not seem to fit on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736412/parser-generator-for-c-sharp-target-that-enables-intellisense-like-code-auto-com). On meta, it was suggested to me to give it a try here. And after reading the Help here this SE site seems to be the right place. Hopefully you'll agree with this assessment.

Comment: If you are willing to "implement your autocomplete", then any parser generator will do.  If you are not willing to generate it, then what you are asking for isn't a parser generator, because it already understands there will be some kind of interactive component; parser generators don't.  This is why Xtext *contains* a parser generator instead of *being* one.

Comment: Something like [Jetbrains Nitra](https://github.com/JetBrains/Nitra)? It's in beta stadium and under heavy development. Worth a look. Can't recommend it, though, because I have too little experience

Comment: There is a library that makes it easy to write a grammar in C# that goes by the name "[Irony - .NET Language Implementation Kit](https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=Irony%20-%20.NET%20Language%20Implementation%20Kit)" currently hosted on the soon to be defunct CodePlex. Although there are few forks on github by third parties.